# Custom post type and custom page name

Tags: custom-post-types

**EDIT: With help of Micheal the answer is single-{post-type}-{slug}.php rather than page-{slug}.php**

I have created a custom post type called "Gallery Pages" and added a page called "First One" So the full path for the page is:

```
example.com/gallerypages/first-one
```

Now I want to make a custom page for this page and obviously this doesn't work:

```
page-first-one.php
```

I have also tried

```
page-gallerypages-first-one.php
```

But it doesn't work either. What is the correct file name for the custom page then?

Comment: have you read https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-post

Comment: Thanks. I was fixed on page-{slug}.php but the answer is single-{slug}.php